# Sidekiq - processing jobs sequentially

Tags: sidekiq, sidekiq-superworker

Is it possible to process jobs sequentially, based on arguments?

**Example jobs:**

Jobs: `[User A, Operation A]`, `[User B, Operation B]`, `[User A, Operation C]`, `[User B, Operation D]`, .. stream of jobs

Process all jobs of each user sequentially, but concurrently across users.

**Example:**

1. Sequentially execute all jobs for User A: Operation A, Operation C
2. Sequentially execute all jobs for User B: Operation B, Operation D

However (1), (2) get executed concurrently.

So far I've looked at Sidekiq Pro, [SuperWorker](https://github.com/socialpandas/sidekiq-superworker), [Gush](https://github.com/chaps-io/gush/issues) to do this, but it doesn't seem supported.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: can you elaborate more on why you can't do this from Gush?